# Regex pattern matching is getting timed out

Tags: java, regex

I want to split an input string based on the regex pattern using `Pattern.split(String)` api. The regex uses both positive and negative lookaheads. The regex is supposed to split on a delimiter (,) and needs to ignore the delimiter if it is enclosed in double inverted quotes("x,y").

The regex is - `(?<!(?<!\Q\\E)\Q\\E)\Q,\E(?=(?:[^\Q"\E]*(?<=\Q,\E)\Q"\E[[^\Q,\E|\Q"\E] | [\Q"\E]]+[^\Q"\E]*[^\Q\\E]*[\Q"\E]*)*[^\Q"\E]*$)`

The input string for which this split call is getting timed out is -

```
"","1114356033020-0011,- [BRACKET],1114356033020-0017,- [FRAME],1114356033020-0019,- [CLIP],1114356033020-0001,- [FRAME ASSY],1114356033020-0013,- [GUSSET],1114356033020-0015,- [STIFFENER]","QH20426AD3 [RIVET,SOL FL HD],UY510AE3L [NUT,HEX],PO41071B0 [SEALING CMPD],LL510A3-10 [\"BOLT,HI-JOK\"]"
```

I read that the lookup technics are heavy and can cause the timeouts if the string is too long. And if I remove the backward slashes enclosing `[\"BOLT,HI-JOK\"]` at the end of the string, then the regex is able to detect and split.

The pattern also does not detect the first delimiter at place `[STIFFENER]","QH20426AD3` with the above string. But if I remove the backward slashes enclosing `[\"BOLT,HI-JOK\"]` at the end of the string, then the regex is able to detect it.

I am not very experienced with the lookup in regex, can some one please give hints about how can I optimize this regex and avoid time outs?
Any pointers, article links are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split on a comma, and the strings that follow are from an opening till closing double quote after it:

```
,(?="[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")
```

The pattern matches:

- `,` Match a comma
- `(?=` Positive lookahad

  - `"[^"\\]*` Match `"` and 0+ times any char except `"` or `\`
  - `(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` Optionally repeat matching `\` to escape any char using the `.` and again match any chars other than `"` and `/`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kho9Wx/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/g2dveL)

```
String string = "\"\",\"1114356033020-0011,- [BRACKET],1114356033020-0017,- [FRAME],1114356033020-0019,- [CLIP],1114356033020-0001,- [FRAME ASSY],1114356033020-0013,- [GUSSET],1114356033020-0015,- [STIFFENER]\",\"QH20426AD3 [RIVET,SOL FL HD],UY510AE3L [NUT,HEX],PO41071B0 [SEALING CMPD],LL510A3-10 [\\\"BOLT,HI-JOK\\\"]\"\n";
String[] parts = string.split(",(?=\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")");
for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println(part);
```

Output

```
""
"1114356033020-0011,- [BRACKET],1114356033020-0017,- [FRAME],1114356033020-0019,- [CLIP],1114356033020-0001,- [FRAME ASSY],1114356033020-0013,- [GUSSET],1114356033020-0015,- [STIFFENER]"
"QH20426AD3 [RIVET,SOL FL HD],UY510AE3L [NUT,HEX],PO41071B0 [SEALING CMPD],LL510A3-10 [\"BOLT,HI-JOK\"]"
```